# Find a function $f$ with given criterion

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Please help me to find a function with a given criterion.

I need a non-negative function $f(x)$ such that

1. $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty }f(x) $ does not  exists
2. $\int\limits_0^{\infty}f(x)\ dx$ exists

I don't know whether such a function exist.

I have tried several function but none of them suit.  If no such function exist then please help me to sketch a proof.

Comment: Any other constraints? For instance, does the function need to be continuous? Is this the Riemann integral?

Comment: To understand @zhw. 's example see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral

Comment: @EugenCovaci Unfortunately that example was not nonnegative. I deleted that comment, but probably shouldn't have. The function I mentioned is $f(x)= \sin (x^2).$

Comment: @zhw. Anyway, your example proves a function doesn't have to have a limit  to $+ \infty$ for the improper integral to exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $f:[0, + \infty) \rightarrow [0, + \infty)$ such that $f(x)=x$ if $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x \notin \mathbb{N}$

Also note the $f(x)$ is non-negative.

We have that the limit if $f(x)$ as $x \rightarrow + \infty$ does not exist.

From Lebesgue's theorem, $f$ is Riemman integrable because is discontinuous in a countable set and every countable set has measure zero.

A set $A$ has measure zero if  $\forall \epsilon>0$ exist a sequence of open intervals $(a_n,b_n)$ such that  $A \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n,b_n)$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(b_n-a_n) \leqslant \epsilon$

Now  $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{k-1}^kf(x)dx$

The O.P as an exercise he/she can prove that $\int_{k-1}^kf(x)dx=0, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ and conclude that $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx=0$

Comment: Can you prove the Riemann integral is zero?

Answer (score 2):

The typical example is to let $f$ be mostly $0$, but have narrower and narrower, evenly spaced spikes from $0$ to $1$ and back to $0$ again as $x\to \infty$. The narrowness of the spikes lets the integral converge, but stops $f$ from having a limit.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the [popcorn function/Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function), which is defined on $[0,1]$.  This has Riemann integral $0$, and is discontinuous only on the rationals.  Make a copy of this on the higher intervals, e.g., $[1,2]$, $[2,3]$, $\dots$, $[n, n+1]$.  Then, clearly, $f$ is non-negative, and $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ doesn't exist (why?), and $\int \limits_{0}^{\infty} f(x)\,dx = \sum \limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \int \limits_{n}^{n + 1} f(x)\,dx = \sum \limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} 0 = 0$.

**EDIT**: By the way, based on your answer history it looks like you proved Thomae's function is continuous on the irrationals, so it looks like you have some experience with this example.

Comment: layman Can you help [Connection of complex $e^z$ and real Dirichlet](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867643/) please?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a real-analytic example:

$$f(x) = \left (\frac{2+\cos x}{3}\right )^{x^3}.$$

The function inside the parentheses equals $1$ at the points $2n\pi, n = 0,1,2,\dots$ Everywhere else it takes values in $[1/3,1).$ The exponent $x^3$ grows rapidly and smashes the thing down close to $0$ at a fast enough rate to lead to a convergent integral. (Why $x^3?$ It has something to do with Laplaces's method.)

I include this just for fun. Triangular spikes are the way to go for intuition.